# Idempotent Elements and Isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Artin in "Algebra" mentions the following:

To determine whether or not a given ring is isomorphic to a product ring, one looks for the elements that in a product ring would be $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. They are idempotent elements.

So I don't think I am understanding this. What does he mean and could someone provide example of using idempotent elements in demonstrating that $\mathbb{Z}/(6)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}/(3)$. I could explicitly list our the isomorphism, but I am trying to understand where the idempotent elements are coming in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a commutative ring $R$ to be isomorphic to a product of rings, there has to exist a non-trivial idempotent $e \in R$ and then one has an isomorphism $R \cong Re \times R (1 - e) $ given by $r \mapsto (r e, r (1-e) )$.

So let us have a look at the idempotents of $R = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. The nontrivial ones are given by the cosets $e_1 = 3 + 6\mathbb{Z}$ (as $3^2 = 9 \equiv 3$ mod $6$ ) and $e_2 = 4 + 6\mathbb{Z}$ (as $4^2 = 16 \equiv 4$ mod $6$). Also $e_1 + e_2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.
We thus have an isomorphism $R \cong R e_1 \times R e_2$. 
Note that we have $$R e_1 = \{0 + 6 \mathbb{Z}, 3 + 6\mathbb{Z}\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$$ and $$R e_2 = \{0 + 6\mathbb{Z}, 2 + 6 \mathbb{Z}, 4 + 6\mathbb{Z}\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! However, sorry I do not understand what you mean by $Re_1$ and $Re_2$? Are they representing the right coset?

Comment: By $R e_1$ I mean the ideal generated by $e_1$ or the set of all elements of the form $r e_1$ for $r \in R$. Since $e_1$ is an idempotent $R e_1$ itself becomes a ring with multiplication and addition inherited from $R$ only that $e_1$ becomes the identity element (you have $e_1 x = x e_1 = x$ for all $x \in R e_1$).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!